# BASH: Read serial to variable and array

Tags: bash, serial-port

I have looked everywhere online for a solution to this and have not found one.  I have a continuous serial input on  ttyACM0 (from an arduino). I would like to be able to read the string line into a variable and then split the characters into an array. The characters in the string are separated by a comma. So far for reading the input, I've done:

```
while true
 do
       cat /dev/ttyACM0
  done
```

so this just spits out the serial input but I have no idea how to accomplish the things I specified above with it.

Thanks

Comment: You want to read the words in the line into an array? Do you want to accumulate the words in the lines into a single array or just deal with each line individually?

Comment: I want to deal with each line individually then for each line read in, I want to split the word or characters in the string into an array based on delimiter comma ( I know I said space though. I'll change that).

Comment: The `-a` argument to `read` will assign to an array instead of individual variables. That and using `IFS` should let you do what you want I believe. Something like `while IFS=, read -a linearr; do # Use the array here; done < /dev/ttyACM0`.

Comment: It said "read: Illegal option -a"

Comment: And I'm in BASH not DASH

Comment: It includes #!/bin/bash

Comment: and what does `echo BASH_VERSION=$BASH_VERSION` return? Good luck.

Comment: If you get that error for `-a` and your shell gives you an error with `<(command)` then you **aren't** using `bash`. And your shebang line doesn't matter if you aren't running your script as `/path/to/script.sh` or `./path/to/script.sh`.

Comment: @Etan Reisner Ok now I'm running it will 'bash file .sh'. Now there is no error but it just prints nothing when I echo ${linearr[*]}; or even when I loop through it nothing happens.

Comment: Post the updated code and some sample input lines. Can you get a `while read` loop to work at all (without `-a`/`IFS` games)?

Comment: Here is the code without the  `-a/IFS`  :                                                    `while read line; do  echo $line done < /dev/ttyACM0` this print `1,2 \n 1,2 \n 1,2` which is my input from the Arduino.

Comment: Ok for some reason now when I put the `-a/IFS` it works perfectly. Although, I am positive doing the exact same thing before made it not work. All I did differently was name the variable `line` instead of `linearr`, which obviously makes no difference.

Comment: And now it just stopped again. It seems to just come and go.

Comment: The functionality can't be changing like that. Which means if it is changing the input must be changing. Are you sure you are consistently getting the input you expect?

Comment: @Etan Reisner: I believe I am. The Arduino IDE show's me a continuous stream of the input I want in its monitor on ttyACM0. However, once in a while I get a short stream of arbitrary characters that are not my input. This happens either on its own, or when I lower the baud rate. Also the BASH code above, even with the IFS and -a, has gone from doing nothing, to spitting 3 lines, to showing a stream and has cycled through these.

Comment: That sounds like they might be serial control characters of some sort then. I'm not familiar enough with this stuff to know what they might be though. You will probably need to filter for those if they are going to be happening. That sounds like the output isn't continuous and/or is buffered somewhere and the control characters might have something to do with that.